# Why does using a comma concatenate strings in PowerShell?

Tags: arrays, string, powershell

I have encountered a PowerShell behavior I don't understand. A comma between strings concatenates them and inserts a space in between, e.g.:

```
PS H:\> [string]$result = "a","b"

PS H:\> $result # a string with 3 characters
a b
```

If the result is interpeted as an array, then using a comma separates the elements of the array, e.g.:

```
PS H:\> [array]$result = "a","b"

PS H:\> $result # an array with 2 elements
a
b
```

I have tried searching for an explanation of this behavior, but I don't really understand what to search for. In the documentation about the `comma operator`, I see that it is used to initialize arrays, but I have not found an explanation for the "string concatenation" (which, I suspect, may not be the correct term to use here).

Comment: It's not the comma - it's the `[string]` constraint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed: `,` is the [array constructor operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-).

Since your variable is a *scalar* - a single `[string]` instance - PowerShell implicitly *stringifies* your array (converts it to a string).

PowerShell **stringifies arrays by joining the (stringified) elements of the array with a *space character* as the separator** by default.
You may set a different separator via the [`$OFS` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#ofs), but that is rarely done in practice.<sup>[1]</sup>

You can observe this behavior in the context of [string interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375):

```
PS> "$( "a","b" )"
a b
```

---

<sup>[1] As [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) points out, an **easier way to specify a different separator** is to use the **[`-join` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Join)**; e.g.,

`"a", "b" -join '@'` yields `'a@b'`.

By contrast, setting `$OFS` without resetting it afterwards can cause later commands that expect it to be at its default to malfunction; with `-join` you get explicit control.</sup>