# Recorded PowerShell Object data to Azure blob as CSV is missing line breaks

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-lake

I am trying to record my data to the Azure blob storage using the next command:

```
    #Get PowerBI metrics
        $Result = Get-PowerBIActivityEvent -StartDateTime 2023-03-13T23:58:59 -EndDateTime 2023-03-13T23:59:59
        $Result = ($Result | ConvertFrom-Json) | Select-Object * 
        $Result = $Result |  ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
    
        Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $TenantId -Credential $Credential
        
# Create a context object using Azure AD credentials
        $ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $accountName -UseConnectedAccount
        $container = Get-AzStorageContainer -Name $containerName -Context $ctx
        $date_loaded = (Get-Date -Format "MMddyyyy").ToString()
        $content = [system.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($Result) 
        $container.CloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference($date_loaded+".csv").UploadFromByteArray($content,0,$content.Length)
```

The file is successfully created but all the records are in one line.
I believe it's something with Encoding but I can't figure out how to fix it.

[image: My]

I know there is an option to record existing file to blob, but it doesn't work for me as I want to run it on cloud and I need direct conversion of the variable to the blob.

Comment: As an aside: `| Select-Object *` is an expensive no-op in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$Result` contains an *array* of strings, because [`ConvertTo-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv) emits the CSV rows it creates *one by one* (which, when captured in a variable, results in a regular PowerShell array, which is of type `[object[]]`).
- This array is *implicitly stringified* (converted to a *single string*) when you call `$content = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($Result)`, which by default concatenates the (stringified) elements *with spaces* (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65145549/45375) for details).

  - That is, there will be *no* newlines in the result (except if the array elements themselves happen to contain any).
- Instead, **you must pass a *single, multiline string*, which you must create explicitly**:

  ```bash
  # To use LF-only newlines, use "`n"
  # To use the platform-native newlines, use [Environment]::NewLine 
  # Alternatively (simple, but slower, with platform-native newlines): 
  #   ($Result | Out-String)
  $content = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($Result -join "`r`n")
  ```

---

Note:

- PowerShell is unusual in that it performs many *automatic* type conversions, unlike other languages.
- While these implicit conversions are *usually* helpful, when it comes to calling *.NET APIs* with `[string]` parameters they are not, as your question demonstrates.

  - Unfortunately, given PowerShell's commitment to backward compatibility, this behavior is unlikely to change.

Comment: I am super grateful for your help!
I spent so much time looking for a solution that I'm embarrassed to mention it

Thank you!

Comment: My pleasure, @OlegKazanskyi; glad to hear that it helped. It's a subtle problem, for sure, and I wish PowerShell worked differently in this case, but it's too late to change that.